# How can i open an executable from an qt application (c++)

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I used that solution, but it looks like it can start only an exe from that target `%windir%\system32\`, like Notepad, WordPad, etc.

For example, I want to start Mozilla or Chrome or any other program that is not in that target.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QProcess *proc = new QProcess(this);
    proc->start("notepad.exe");
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the full path. notepad.exe works since the path to them is in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Just define the absolute path to the executable: Like
`C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\firefox.exe`
(I don't have Windows next to me right now, so the path to the firefox.exe can be different).

Comment: Thank you. But what if i add the Mozilla path in the PATH enviroment variabile, it should be working ?

Answer (score 0):

This has more to do with how an OS works. When using the cmd and type commands you actually execute a program which is in the path (like system32). There is no way to execute a program which isn't in a path location and you don't know the location except if you want to implement a search feature.